# Titan receive edge which connects any nodes of two sets

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I am trying to retrieve all edges which connect any of the nodes in set A and one of the nodes in set B. 
Current approach:

```
 ArrayList<Vertex> nodeStartList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getStartNode(), g, snapshotId);
    ArrayList<Vertex> nodeEndList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getEndNode(), g, snapshotId);
```

The vertex lists are correctly filled (Already checked that)

```
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Edge> tempOutput = g.V(nodeStartList.toArray()).bothE().where(__.is(P.within(nodeEndList.toArray()))).hasLabel(relationshipStorage.getId());
```

But I always retrieve an empty list from output.
And I'm sure I have edges matching my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that works:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open();
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> v1 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v2 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v3 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v4 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v5 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v6 = graph.addVertex();
gremlin> v1.addEdge("edgeLabel", v4);
gremlin> v2.addEdge("edgeLabel", v5);
gremlin> v3.addEdge("edgeLabel", v6);
```

The above creates 6 vertices with 3 edges between them. I can then find those edges with:

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V(v1, v2, v3).bothE().filter(otherV().is(within(v4, v5, v6)))
==>e[6][0-edgeLabel->3]
==>e[7][1-edgeLabel->4]
==>e[8][2-edgeLabel->5]
```

Comment: what's the "edges" for? That's a gremlin constants?

Comment: It's just a label for what result I would like to retrieve from the traversal. I could have said `as("bob")` and then at the end say `select("bob")`. More info on that [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#select-step)

Comment: Ah understood it's like if I have check all nodes "n1" and "n2" and edges "e" but return only e.
If I do it without the as and select, I guess it may just return nodes as well?

Comment: If you do it without the `select` you will get the results at the end of the traversal which in this case will just be your target nodes `v4`, `v5`, and `v6`

Comment: do I have to do it with "hasId" or is it possible to let it receive just the plain vertices as  in "V()" at the start?

Comment: ArrayList<Vertex> nodeStartList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getStartNode(), g, snapshotId);
        ArrayList<Vertex> nodeEndList =  getVertexList(relationshipStorage.getEndNode(), g, snapshotId);

        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Edge> tempOutput = g.V(nodeStartList.toArray()).bothE().as("edges").otherV().hasId(nodeEndList.stream().map(Element::id).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray()).select("edges");

I tried the above but I always received an empty result, strange.

Comment: I've tweaked the traversal a bit. The result stays the same, but neither `hasId()` nor path labeling were necessary.